# SQL SELECT based on 3 other tasbles value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

## One SQL Query

I am trying to select books from the Books tables based on a reference BookID from other tables. I would like to have this as one query if possible. Here is what I have so far.

- `SELECT BookID FROM TitleMeta WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%`
- `SELECT BookID FROM AuthorMeta WHERE Author LIKE '%$search%';`
- `SELECT BookID FROM LocationMeta WHERE Location LIKE '%$search%';`

and then from those results:

`SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookID=BookID;`

If anyone could help me achieve this as one query where you `SELECT *
 FROM Books WHERE BookID =`   each of `BookID`'s from the three queries above I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: use Union  and bookid exists

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to get BookID From three table. You can use `UNION` combine those table to become `BookID` table and you can use  `WHERE BookId IN` the table.

Simple like this

```
SELECT * FROM Books WHERE BookID IN
(
    SELECT BookID FROM TitleMeta WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%'
    UNION 
    SELECT BookID FROM AuthorMeta WHERE Author LIKE '%$search%'
    UNION 
    SELECT BookID FROM LocationMeta WHERE Location LIKE '%$search%'
)
```

**Three tables are large tables**

Maybe you can try it.

```
 SELECT Books.* 
 FROM Books,
(
    SELECT BookID FROM TitleMeta WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%'
    UNION 
    SELECT BookID FROM AuthorMeta WHERE Author LIKE '%$search%'
    UNION 
    SELECT BookID FROM LocationMeta WHERE [Location] LIKE '%$search%'
) AS BookGroupID
WHERE 
    BookGroupID.BookID = BookGroupID.BookID
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer, and makes no assumptions about the database design - it just answers the question as stated.

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk, but have to I disagree with @e_i_pi .  This solution makes the same assumption that all the others do (mine included), that BookId corresponds to BookId in all the tables.  I think the sub-queries in the Where clause are unnecessary and, frankly, not very desirable if these are large tables. Sorry.

Comment: BTW, I didn't down-vote this or anything.  Just thought those other points were worth mentioning.

Comment: @jwolf  thank you advice,
ButI I just answer the question from questioner 
SQL SELECT based on 3 other tasbles value, and we don’t know three 
tables schema. I add another query SQL solution for assumption three tables are large tables.

Comment: @jwolf Gee I don't know what I was thinking here, long day at the office. You're dead right. Nonetheless, the amendment provided is much more performant than the other solutions when you start getting thousands of records.

Comment: I'd love to race them just for fun.  By the way @e_i_pi , Very Cool Logo!

Comment: @jwolf I'd put up a fiddle, but I can't get a fiddle to create schema properly with the number of records it takes before you see divergence in execution times :(

Answer (score 1):

try this code maybe help you

```
    SELECT * FROM Books 
    WHERE BookID in (SELECT BookID FROM TitleMeta WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%') 
    or BookID in (SELECT BookID FROM AuthorMeta WHERE Author LIKE '%$search%') 
    or bookID in (SELECT BookID FROM LocationMeta WHERE Location LIKE '%$search%')
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Books 
    WHERE BookID in (SELECT BookID FROM TitleMeta WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%') 
    or BookID in (SELECT BookID FROM AuthorMeta WHERE Author LIKE '%$search%') 
    or bookID in (SELECT BookID FROM LocationMeta WHERE Location LIKE '%$search%')

Answer (score 1):

### I Think This Should Be Faster...

...No sub-queries, and the left joins make sure you get all the results without any assumptions about database design or completeness.

```
select b.*
    from Books b
    left join TitleMeta t on t.BookId = b.BookId
    left join AuthorMeta a on a.BookId = b.BookId
    left join LocationMeta l on l.BookId = b.BookId
    where t.Title like '%$search%' or a.Author like '%$search%' or l.Location like '%$search%'
```

This will find any books where the [one] search string might be the Title, might be the Author, or might be the Location; and returns any hits.

Note the Left Joins: a BookId need not be represented in each of the 3 look-up tables to be valid.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some assumptions about your table relationships, but this should be the best way to do this on a DB lacking CTE capabilities -

```
select * from Books where BookID in (
  SELECT TM.BookID FROM TitleMeta TM
  join AuthorMeta AM on TM.BookID = AM.BookID
  join LocationMeta LM on TM.BookID = LM.BookID
  WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%'
  or author LIKE '%$search%'
  or Location LIKE '%$search%')
```

Comment: It's a MySQL Server using PHPMyAdmin for simplicity sake. I am still new to SQL Queries so still using the GUI for now. As for CTE, not sure.